# systemd-resolved - how to stop forwarding and go direct to DNSBLs / RBLs (mailserver blacklists)

Tags: systemd-resolved

My mailserver needs to check IPs of incoming connections against external blacklists, this is done by a DNS lookup but it must go direct to the blacklist and not via the usual configured DNS forwarding servers.

(Reason: My queries to various DNS blacklists are otherwise rejected, since they go through my provider's nameservers - along with fellow customers' - and reach the limit imposed by blacklists for free queries per IP address. This way I continue to use blacklists to spam check the small amount of e-mail I get, without having to turn off the forwarding/caching entirely.)

I have been using bind9 which offers a way to do this for individual DNS zones within /etc/bind/named.conf.options thus:

```
zone "zen.spamhaus.org" { type forward; forward first; forwarders {}; };
```

For more information on bind9 solution see serverfault post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/514247/tell-bind-to-not-forward-for-domains-used-by-dns-block-list-services).

Is this possible using systemd-resolved (v237 or greater) instead of bind9, and if so how? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I would prefer deactivating systemd-resolved and using dnsmasq. Or you can actually use both. keep using it for system queries, and direct the email daemon to dnsmasq in another port, like 5353

Comment: thanks, but using two concurrent dns resolvers just makes life more complicated when I want to make it simpler. systemd-resolved is becoming the default DNS resolver (because systemd is taking over anyway). I have bind9 working but it seems like overkill for such a small problem.

Comment: Have a look at dnsmask, it is lightweight and has a couple of nifty features. You won't be sorry. It also does caching and comes by default in a couple of distros

Comment: For anyone else looking here, I have stayed with bind9 which continues to do a good job. The line for forwarding (in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`) can be simplified thus:

`zone "zen.spamhaus.org" { type forward; forwarders {}; };`